# Prove that taking the inverse Fourier transform of frequency returns time.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, mathematical-modeling, dirac-delta, formal-proofs

If we evaluate the inverse Fourier transform of  X(w) how do we know we get x(t) back?

[Link to X(w) and x(t) equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coCW8.png)

I know that integrating in the frequency domain results in getting information back in the time domain, and vice versa simply due to the definition of frequency. However, mathematically, how can we integrate an arbitrary function that we don't know the characteristics of? Can we substitute another function, such as the delta function in place of X(w) or the exponential? Do we need to use convolution? Mathematically, I'm stumped. Logically, it's clear to see, I just don't understand the proof.

Comment: what you are asking is called the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem). you should look  at the Fourier series first, and even at the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). the DFT (of size $n$) is an orthonormal matrix $n \times n$. for the Fourier series it is the same, but in infinite dimensional vector space : the proof is based on the fact that $(e^{2 i \pi n x})_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,1])$ the (Hilbert) space of square integrable functions $[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There are many concepts that come together in Fourier Analysis and it can feel like a big mess sometimes. I don't know if me explaining will help at that point, just keep reading and let your brain munch on it for a bit.